VBA or formula to repeat a list of items, and for each repeated list, add a location name from a separate locations list
I have a list of items that I want to repeat multiple times, once for each location. Then I need to add the location to an adjacent column for each item. I'm looking for a macro or formula that would populate this automatically because right now it's a lot of copy paste and drag down.
So my list of items is on the Items tab in column A.



Column A




12456


13967


15786



Then location names are on the Stores tab in column A.



Column A




San Francisco


Dallas


New York



On a new tab I want the item list in column B for each store in column A.



Column A
Column B




San Francisco
12456


San Francisco
13967


San Francisco
15786


Dallas
12456


Dallas
13967


Dallas
15786


New York
12456


New York
13967


New York
15786



I've searched but haven't found any info on this specific problem.

Have you attempted to record a macro?  By tagging vba, you are indicating you have code that you have tried.  Please provide that code.  Note that SO is not a code-for-you service, but a service to aid in resolving a specific issue with what you have attempted/tried.

First, I would use CTRL + T to make both of these lists tables.
Then, in the Data tab of excel from table/range I'd load these both to power query.
Then, in the power query window under the Home tab I added a New Source from a blank query. I put the name of one table into the formula bar. Then Added a Custom Column and made that formula the name of the other table.

Expanding this added column will create the list of combinations.


Finally, close & load to your spreadsheet. Then you can refresh this output table and it will apply the logic to the tables if new information is added or deleted.


That did it!  The item and stores list changes often so that's great I can just edit the table.   Thank you!

=LET(R,LAMBDA(a,b,[c],TOCOL(IF(TOROW(LEN(a)),b),,c)),HSTACK(R(B1:B3,D1:D4),R(D1:D4,B1:B3,1)))
Change the ranges to your needs.

Power Query is nice, but this'd work as well (without needing refresh):

Automatically include new entries with
XLOOKUP(TRUE, Items!A:A <> "", Items!A:A, , , -1)
(look for last non-blank entry in column)

TOCOL in available in Microsoft 365
=LET(
    items, Items!A1:XLOOKUP(TRUE, Items!A:A <> "", Items!A:A, , , -1),
    stores, Stores!A1:XLOOKUP(TRUE, Stores!A:A <> "", Stores!A:A, , , -1),
    TOCOL(stores & " " & TRANSPOSE(items))
)



Sub items_stores()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim n As Long

Range("A:B").Clear

m = 1
n = 1

j = Sheets("Items").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = Sheets("Stores").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For k = 1 To j

For l = 1 To i

Cells(m, 1).Value = Sheets("Items").Cells(k, 1).Value

Cells(m, 2).Value = Sheets("Stores").Cells(n, 1).Value

n = n + 1 
If n = i + 1 Then
n = 1
Else
End If

m = m + 1

Next l

Next k

End Sub

